# IntelliJ won't open on Mac: error message displays "This application "IntelliJ IDEA" can't be opened."

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have been using IntelliJ for about 6 months now on my Mac and it has always worked perfectly fine. For context, I have also been using PyCharm without any problems as well. Now, whenever I try opening IntelliJ, I only receive that error message.

I've tried accessing it through the terminal but it isn't working. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Edit: After giving it a day and reinstalling the IDE, it seems like it is back to full functionality.

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000120784-Can-t-open-IntelliJ-on-MacOs)?

Comment: You need to check the log. Ref [Locating IDE log files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files). My log file is located in`~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.3/idea.log`

Comment: I have tried locating the log files but I only receive this message: zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/person/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2

Comment: @LuffyDamonke Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: is this message popups show on macOS or IntelliJ?

Comment: Please share the console output (error message) you receive when [running IntelliJ from terminal](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line)? Another thing you can try is to reinstall IntelliJ by downloading it from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download). For further analysis you can submit a support request [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731).